# How are these two sentences related?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be a transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, represented by the matrix:

$$
  T =
  \left [ { \begin{array}{cc}
  0 & -1 \\
  1 &  0  \\
  \end{array} } \right ]
$$

> The eigenvalues of this matrix are $i$ and $-i$.

[In this video by 3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFDu9oVAE-g), he says that this particular fact has directly related to another fact:

> Multiplying a complex number by $i$, is equivalent to rotating the complex plane by $90^0$ and checking where the original complex number (point in complex plane) lands.

How are these two facts related? How could a fact about matrices in $\mathbb{R}^2$ having complex valued eigenvalues be related to a fact about complex planes and a relationship between complex numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matrix $T =
  \left [ { \begin{array}{cc}
  0 & -1 \\
  1 &  0  \\
  \end{array} } \right ]$ corresponds to $i$ in complex number.

Consider $T^2$, it is equal to $- I$, just like $i^2 = -1$ in ordinary number.

Another way to think of it is by change of coordinates, the rotation matrix $T =
  \left [ { \begin{array}{cc}
  \cos \theta & - \sin \theta \\
   \sin \theta &   \cos \theta  \\
  \end{array} } \right ]$,

plug in $\theta = \pi /2 $, this corresponds to rotation by $\pi /2$, which is equivalent to $i$

---

Just added:

Next, by the matrix equation $Av=\lambda v$. Left side means rotation by $\pi /2$, if you relate $v$ to a complex number, this just means $i$ times $v$, so $Av=i v$, equivalent to the fact that eigenvalue is $i$.

Comment: The matrix corresponds to $i$, fine. But what does that have to do with the fact that the eigenvalues are $i$ and $-i$

Comment: Consider the following the matrix equation $Av= \lambda v$, when $v$ is column vector （which is quite similar to complex number）. Then $Av$ is intuitively a rotation by $\pi /2$, and equivalently $i$ times  $v$, just  as the right side of the equation.

Comment: Please add that to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Another view: $T$ generalizes to something called an almost complex structure on, say, a vector bundle. The only condition is that $J$ is a linear operator such that $J^2 = - \textrm{Id}$; such structures are valuable because they admit a $\mathbb{C}$-module structure on an otherwise real vector space by defining $i x := Jx$ for $x \in V$, where $V$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. Since $J$ satisfies its own characteristic polynomial (Cayley-Hamilton), the condition $J^2 = - \textrm{Id}$ implies that there are eigenvalues $\pm i$.

You can construct these on $\mathbb{C}^n$ in a natural way: look at the endomorphism induced by multiplying vectors by $i$ when viewing $\mathbb{C}^n$ as $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. In your example, consider $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the standard fashion; that is, $x+ i y \mapsto (x,y)$. Then, look at the induced matrix transformation when multiplying by $i$ on each basis vector. We see
$$i \cdot (1,0) = i \cdot 1 = i = (0,1)$$
and 
$$i \cdot (0,1) = i \cdot i = -1 = (-1,0)$$
Thus the induced endomorphism when viewing $i$ as a transformation of $\mathbb{C}$ as a real vector space is precisely the matrix
$$T = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
And, of course, $i = e^{i \pi/2}$ in the complex plane, which means that multiplication by $i$ is the same as rotating a complex number $90$ degrees. Thus we deduce that $T$ as above has the effect of rotating a real vector $90$ degrees in $\mathbb{R}^2$.